# Calculate sum and average of a column in a pyspark dataframe and create a new row for the calculated values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe

```text
Place   Month       Sector      Estimate    Profit  
USA     1/1/2020    Sector1     5944
Col     1/1/2020    Sector1     398
IND     1/1/2020    Sector1     25
USA     1/1/2020    Sector2                 6.9%
Col     1/1/2020    Sector2                 0.4%
China   1/1/2020    Sector2                 0.0%
Aus     1/1/2020    Sector2                 7.7%
```

I need to calculate the sum of all `Estimate` column(include all values) and average of all `Profit` column (excluding 0.0%) grouped by `Month` and `Sector`.

I need an extra value in Place field as `Every Places` having these sum and average values. So, my desired dataframe should look like this:

```text
Place           Month       Sector      Estimate    Profit  
USA             1/1/2020    Sector1     5944
Col             1/1/2020    Sector1     398
IND             1/1/2020    Sector1     25
USA             1/1/2020    Sector2                 6.9%
Col             1/1/2020    Sector2                 0.4%
China           1/1/2020    Sector2                 0.0%
Aus             1/1/2020    Sector2                 7.7%
Every Places    1/1/2020    Sector1     6367
Every Places    1/1/2020    Sector2                 5%
```

I tried with this code, but I'm getting:

> TypeError: Column is not iterable` error.

```
df1=df.withColumn('Place',lit('Every Places')) \
               .groupBy('Month','Sector') \
               .sum((col('Estimate'))),
               avg(F.col('Profit'))
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: try groupBy().agg(sum(col('Estimate').as('Estimate'), avg(col('Profit').as('Profit'))
Then you can union this dataframe with the original dataframe after adding additional column Place to get the required Output

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of this pls? @NikunjKakadiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first group by `Month` + `Sector` to calculate the sum of `Estimate` and the average of `Profit` then use union with the original dataframe to get the expected output:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("USA", "1/1/2020", "Sector1", 5944, None), ("Col", "1/1/2020", "Sector1", 398, None),
    ("IND", "1/1/2020", "Sector1", 25, None), ("USA", "1/1/2020", "Sector2", None, "6.9%"),
    ("Col", "1/1/2020", "Sector2", None, "0.4%"), ("China", "1/1/2020", "Sector2", None, "0.0%"),
    ("Aus", "1/1/2020", "Sector2", None, "7.7%")], ["Place", "Month", "Sector", "Estimate", "Profit"]
)

grouped_df = df.withColumn(
    "Profit",
    F.regexp_extract("Profit", "(.+)%", 1) # extract percentage from string
).groupBy("Month", "Sector").agg(
    F.sum(F.col("Estimate")).alias("Estimate"),
    F.concat(
        F.sum("Profit") / F.sum(F.when(F.col("Profit") > 0.0, 1)), # exclude 0% from calculation
        F.lit("%")
    ).alias("Profit")
).withColumn(
    "Place",
    F.lit("Every Places")
)

df1 = df.unionByName(grouped_df)

df1.show()
#+------------+--------+-------+--------+------+
#|       Place|   Month| Sector|Estimate|Profit|
#+------------+--------+-------+--------+------+
#|         USA|1/1/2020|Sector1|    5944|  null|
#|         Col|1/1/2020|Sector1|     398|  null|
#|         IND|1/1/2020|Sector1|      25|  null|
#|         USA|1/1/2020|Sector2|    null|  6.9%|
#|         Col|1/1/2020|Sector2|    null|  0.4%|
#|       China|1/1/2020|Sector2|    null|  0.0%|
#|         Aus|1/1/2020|Sector2|    null|  7.7%|
#|Every Places|1/1/2020|Sector2|    null|  5.0%|
#|Every Places|1/1/2020|Sector1|  6367.0|  null|
#+------------+--------+-------+--------+------+
```

Comment: I tried with this code, but when I unionNyName the dataframes,
Im getting:
 
`AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the right attributes: 'Estimate', 'Profit'`

Comment: @user175025 this is weird... can you try to run the full working example I added?